# Pull values from child arrays to populate parent array

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

I have the below array, that needs some additional structuring.

```
Array
(
[-Others] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [products_sold] => 1
                [products_total_sales] => 2.99
                [products_total_costs] => 1.75
                [products_total_profit] => 1.24
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [products_sold] => 1
                [products_total_sales] => 2.3322
                [products_total_costs] => 1.75
                [products_total_profit] => 0.5822
            )

    )

[Addict] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [products_sold] => 1
                [products_total_sales] => 35.1
                [products_total_costs] => 40
                [products_total_profit] => -4.9
            )
```

I have truncated this early, obviously. I was wondering if it would be possible to add up all the sales for all child products, the `products_total_sales` per brand (aka `addict`)

I would like to get it in before they are parsed so something like:

```
[Addict] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        [brand_total_sales] => '$value'
            (
                [products_sold] => 1
                ...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance and feel free to ask if you need more information

Comment: So you want to add [Addict][0], [1], [2], etc. [products_total_sales] and store them in [Addict][brand_total_sales]?

Comment: I answered before you commented, is that working?

Comment: I think so yeah. Could you elaborate each variable? (or would that be too cheeky to ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in case the answer is yes:

```
foreach($array as $brand_name => $brand_array) {
    $array[$brand_name]['brand_total_sales'] = 0;

    foreach($brand_array as $product) {
        $array[$brand_name]['brand_total_sales'] += $product['products_total_sales'];
    }
}
```